# Enviar e-mail em nome do cliente

Tags: java, envio-de-email

Tenho um sistema que serve a vários clientes e que envia e-mails a seus usuários (clientes dos meus clientes).

Hoje eu uso uma conta de e-mail própria (do meu domínio), e na composição do e-mail eu informo o nome e e-mail do cliente.

Com isso, tenho dois problemas:

1. Estes e-mails vão para a caixa de spam.
2. O destinatário não pode
   responder o e-mail, pois ele não irá para o remetente indicado, e
   sim a minha conta.

**Qual seria a melhor forma de enviar estes e-mails? Obrigo o cliente a configurar uma conta de e-mail própria (correndo o risco de estourar seu limite de envio diário)?**

*Obs: Envio o e-mail usando javax.mail*

Comment: Sugestão: use um serviço como o [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) ou o [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/).

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é ter uma conta específica para o sistema enviar os e-mails, como visto por aí: `no-reply@dominio.com.br`, mas na verdade o endereço não faz tanta diferença. O importante é contratar um plano adequado que suporte o volume de e-mails esperado.

Geralmente os e-mails de empresas são enviados através da mesma hospedagem que eles contratam para o site, que acaba limitando a quantidade de e-mails para os planos básicos. Consulte a empresa responsável sobre a capacidade atual e pergunte por planos para aumentar a capacidade.

Outra alternativa é utilizar outro serviço específico para os e-mails. Mesmo com o domínio de um site associado pelo DNS a uma hospedagem específica, é possível redirecionar o envio e recebimento para endereços diferentes, geralmente através do painel de controle ou mesmo solicitando ao suporte da hospedagem. Dessa forma, você fica livre para contratar um serviço confiável de e-mails sem alterar o funcionamento do site da empresa.

Comment: O problema é que os clientes insistem que o remetente da mensagem tenha o seu domínio, pois é o domínio que seus usuários conhecem.

Comment: Não há problema em enviar é-mails com o domínio dos usuários. Entretanto, se o serviço de e-mail que eles usam é ruim, eles vão ter que trocar. Os limites de envio de e-mails de hospedagens geralmente são especificados em contrato. Faça uma consulta na empresa responsável pelos e-mails.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Reformulei a resposta. Veja se ajuda um pouco mais.

Comment: Entendi. então a solução é mesmo autenticar/enviar o e-mail pelo servidor do cliente.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Isso depende do serviço contratado. Por exemplo, o serviço da Amazon citado na resposta do Emerson não usaria a autenticação no servidor do cliente. Mas se for uma hospedagem "comum", aí sim seria a autenticação SMTP tradicional usando as credenciais do cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, **seu servidor precisa estar bem configurado** ou será considerado como spammer até que o esteja. Isso ocorre por causa da [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](http://antispam.br/admin/spf/). Isso deve ser feito a nível de servidor.

Existem diversos locais que explicam como enviar e-mail de várias linguagens, então vou me focar em resolver seu problema principal, e não como fazer na linguagem.

### Solução de envio direto de seus servidores

Configure seu servidor para trabalhar atender as exigências de Sender Policy Framework. Isso não é trivial, e você será responsável por ver reclamações de SPAM, ou mesmo com ele configurado poderá ter o IP banido.

**Esta solução tende a dar mais trabalho se a quantidade de envio de e-mails é enorme e ao mesmo tempo.**

### Solução de envio via *gateways* de e-mail pagos que garantem entrega

Caso você não consiga configurar SPF, uma opção viável é contratar serviços de gateway de email, como [Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES)](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/), que liberam dados de acesso (por exemplo, dados de SMTP que você poderia enviar de qualquer lugar) e farão o serviço pra você.

**Esta solução tende é mais simples que configurar SPF, porém é mais cara. Permite enviar grande quantidade de e-mails com menos dor de cabeça.**

### Solução simples e funcional para poucos e-mails

Crie uma conta do Gmail, habilite SMTP e configure seu framework para enviar como se fosse por essa conta do Gmail. Funciona muito bem e é a mais barata e fácil de garantir que seus e-mails vão chegar em 100% do tempo, porém requer que você não envie MUITOS emails ao mesmo tempo.

Caso use o [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/intx/pt-BR/enterprise/apps/business/) o email será exatamente o do domínio do cliente, porém a cota gratuita hoje em dia não permite muitas contas diferentes, porém é suficiente para pequenas empresas.

Comment: Se entendi bem, na forma "robusta" eu teria que configurar o servidor de e-mails de cada cliente de forma que eles aprovem que meu servidor enviem e-mails em nome deles. É isso?

Comment: Bem, na prática o servidor que vai entrar em contato com resto do mundo deve ter SPF bem configurado. Seu servidor não precisa exigir SPF de seus clientes para receber e-mail deles, mas Google, Hotmail, e afins, exigem. E mesmo com SPF, envio de e-mails em massa vai exigir uma aplicação que agende e divida a carga de trabalho, ou mesmo com SPF enviar milhares de e-mail em uma hora **vai fazer e-mails entrarem na caixa de SPAM** se seu IP não for previamente confiável.

Answer (score 0):

Note que temos alguns atributos na mensagem como o From, onde você pode setar o email do cliente. Já em relação a configurações do servidor, não sei como ajudar no momento.

```
// File Name SendHTMLEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendHTMLEmail
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "web@gmail.com";

        // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "localhost";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try{
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
            message.setContent("<h1>This is actual message</h1>",
                "text/html" );

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é o que eu faço atualmente, ou seja, eu me autentico em meu mailserver e envio com o remetente do cliente. E é por isso que as mensagens acabam caindo no spam.

Comment: Hummm entendi agora